# Count number of posts for a user from a custom taxonomy that has a specific term meta value (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display a count (for logged in user) that shows how many books they have in the library.

**library** is the name of the custom taxonomy, and the returned count should only be for termmeta where the meta key **library_status** does not have a value of **archived**.

Here's my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'book',
    'post_status'       => array('publish', 'private'),
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'book_status',
    'meta_value'        => array('written', 'un-written', 'on-hold', 'under-review'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'library'
        )
    ),
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array( 
            'key'     => 'library_status',
            'value'   => 'archived',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
$my_posts_count = $posts->post_count;
return $my_posts_count;
```

At the moment it always returns nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's hard for me to figure out what terms apply to what, but couldn't you get the book objects from a taxonomy query, then count the ones with the given author. statuses. and values (or as results of a second query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant accomplish this with using `WP_Query` it does not have support for termmeta

the `meta_query` you define will query the meta of the object for the table you are querying, since WP_Query will query on posts_table, the `meta_query` will query the `wp_postmeta` table

you need to use RAW sql query,
Something like below(untested)

```
SELECT COUNT(p.ID) /* count the id result*/

FROM wp_posts p /* query post table*/

/* inner join table that holds postmeta with meta_key and meta_value filter*/
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
    AND pm.meta_key = 'book_status'
    AND pm.meta_value IN ('written', 'un-written', 'on-hold', 'under-review')

/* inner join table that holds relatinship between post and taxonomy*/
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID 

/* inner join table that holds the taxonomy and filter by name*/
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
    ON tt.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'library' 

/* inner join table that holds the termmeta and filter by key and value */
INNER JOIN wp_termmeta tm 
    ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id 
    AND tm.meta_key = 'library_status'
    AND tm.meta_value NOT IN ('archived') # or use != operator AND tm.meta_value != 'archived' 

/* Additional post filter */
WHERE  p.post_type = 'book'
AND p.post_status IN ('publish', 'private')
AND p.post_author = 1
```

Paste it on SQL tab inside PhpMyAdmin and make sure you get the correct result you desire,
then you can use use it on wodpress `$wpdb` like so;

```
global $wpdb;
$id = get_current_user_id();
return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
.
.
.
AND p.post_author = {$id}
.
.
.
");
```